# Why i cannot start service web?

Tags: python, django, web, service, endpoint

Help me with this error please.

> ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: driver failed programming
>   external connectivity on endpoint semestral_dj01
>   (335d0ad4599512f3228b4ed0bd1bfed96f54af57cff4a553d88635f80ac2e26c):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated ERROR:
>   Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way i resolved this was by stopping the containers in execution and executing the one I wanted to start.

Use this command into your CMD for stop containers:

> docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

In the case you may want to delete them use this:

> docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Terminal and run command:

```
lsof -i:8000
```

Where 8000 is the port number.

The result will be like:

```
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Python      123456      user   ab   type  123    000      TCP  0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now run command in terminal:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

like

```
kill -9 123456
```

Then again run your server and the issue will be resolved.

Comment: i did it but the problem is the same. (port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.).

Answer (score 1):

This happen to me time to time in my dev environment. Usually I have to restart docker service to get it working.

Comment: I just added other possible ports so that I do not have this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a very similar error.  In my case, I had recently upgraded the native *nginx* version on the Linux box.  After the upgrade, *nginx* automatically started (I had not noticed).  When I deployed a docker image with *nginx*, the **2 *nginx* instances were competing for the same port** (native and docker).

I saw it with:

```
> sudo netstat -nl -p tcp  | grep 443
tcp     0a     0 0.0.0.0:443     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN     #####/nginx: master
tcp6    0      0 :::443          :::*          LISTEN     #####/nginx: master
```

It was a bit confusing since I was trying to get *nginx* to run, and it said *nginx* was using the port.  After I had typed `docker-compose down`, I realized *nginx* was still using the port, even though the *nginx* container was destroyed.  That made me realize that the native *nginx* had started up again, even though I didn't manually start it.

My error message:

> Cannot start service <webserver>: **driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint** <server_instance>_webserver (...<guid>...): Error starting userland proxy: listen **tcp 0.0.0.0:443**: bind: **address already in use**